# Try to connect via script to multiple servers

Tags: bash

I am trying to connect to multiple servers from file (servers.txt --> something around 300 IP add) and some server is RHEL5, some RHEL7 (so I must use a diff command).

I can connect to multiple server, its OK, but I can't continue with some condition: like if you don't know one command use another command.

```
#!/bin/bash
for host in $(cat servers.txt); do
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$host

#when I try to continue with "if" -> of course I am logout from servers
```

Comment: This sound like task for https://www.ansible.com/ or https://www.chef.io/products/chef-infra/

Comment: The problems with your script are that the for loop doesn't end with a done and that the if clause is not part of the ssh command arguments, but is part of the parent script. I have added an answer for these below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @rkosegi that this can be achieved an Ansible ad-hoc command, but you'd have to convert the list of servers to an inventory - a very simple task.

At the bash prompt, I think I understand what you want. You want to try multiple commands via each ssh command. So let's assume you want to check the version of the redhat-release package and take different actions from that:

```
while read HOST; do
  ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$HOST '
    VERSION="`rpm -q --queryformat "%{VERSION}" redhat-release`"
    if [[ $VERSION == 5* ]]; then # RHEL5
      echo this is a rhel5
    elif [[ $VERSION == 7* ]]; then # RHEL7
      echo this is a rhel7
    else
      echo this is neither a rhel5 or rhel7
    fi
  '
done <servers.txt
```

Of course, the script can be written on one line, but I thought I'd format it nicer here for increased readability.

Note: The post being tagged with bash, the above command also uses [[ tests which are specific to bash and won't work on some other shells.